# Docker so slow while installing pip requirements

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to implement a docker for a dummy local Django project. I am using `docker-compose` as a tool for defining and running multiple containers. Here I tried to containerize the `Django-web-app` and `PostgreSQL` two services.

*Configuration used in `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml`*

**Dockerfile**

```
# Pull base image
FROM python:3.7-alpine

# Set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Set work directory
WORKDIR /code

# Install dependencies
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy project
COPY . /code/
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.7'

services:
    web:
        build: .
        command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
        volumes: 
            - .:/code
        ports:
            - "8000:8000"
        depends_on:
            - db
    db:
        image: postgres:11
        volumes:
            - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
volumes:
    postgres_data:
```

All seems okay. The path postgres integrations and all except one thing `pip install -r requirements.txt`. This is taking too much time to install from requirements. Last time I was giving up on this but at last the installation does completed but takes lots of time to complete.

In my scenario, the only issue is why the `pip install`  so slow. If there is anything that I am missing? I am new to docker and any help on this topic will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

I was following this [Link](https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/).

Comment: How long is it taking? How many dependencies do you have?

Comment: I think it almost took 15-20 minutes.

Comment: Update to the above answer. I checked the exact time. Although the decent internet speed, it took 9 minutes to complete.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Probably this is because PyPI wheels don’t work on Alpine. Instead of using precompile files Alpine downloads the source code and compile it. Try to use `python:3.7-slim` image instead:

```
# Pull base image
FROM python:3.7-slim

# Set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Set work directory
WORKDIR /code

# Install dependencies
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy project
COPY . /code/
```

Check this article for more details: [Alpine makes Python Docker builds 50× slower](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/alpine-docker-python/).

Comment: Wow :). I will implement this in my dummy project and will get back to accept the answer. Thank you :)

Comment: `python:3.7-slim` was fast :). I could not install `psycopg2` with `python:3.7-slim` and `python:3.7-alpine`.  Is there any way to solve this. Or am I missing anything?

Comment: @dipesh probably you forgot to install something check this examples: https://www.rockyourcode.com/install-psycopg2-binary-with-docker/

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Thank you for your astonishing answer :).

Comment: only gotcha is a (significantly) bigger image size when compared to alpine based, but what's life without trade-offs, eh?